# How to set a bug status to 'Reopened' in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

How do I add a state to a Bug with `Value = Reopened`.

We have only `New`, `Active`, `Resolved` and `Closed` configured in the bug status dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The New, Active, Resolved and closed states are the Default State for the Bug Work item.

From you screenshot, you are using the Default Agile Process. The default agile process cannot be changed. So you need to create an inherited Agile process. Then you could modify the inherited process.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create an inherited Agile process in **Organization Settings -> Process**.

[image]

Step2: Add the Reopend state to Bug Work item in **New Inherited Agile process -> Bug -> States -> New state**.

[image]

In order for your project to use this new inheritance process, you need to change the project process in **Organization Settings -> Process -> Agile(Default) -> Projects ->Change Process**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. [Create an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) if you do not have one already (i.e if you are using one of the built in processes), and c[hange process used by your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#migrate) to use the new one
2. Add a [custom state to your process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-a-workflow-state)

Answer (score -1):

The type of states available seem to be defined by the project settings.

According to [Microsoft Azure DevOps Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#state-categories) it seems like the state categories you mention come from setting the project as `Agile Process`.

The same documentation page also lets us know that you can add custom states. Presumably if you have the correct permissions to do so.
Also, please consider updating your title to something like "How to set bug to state 'Responded' in Azure Devops?", or something similar, descriptive.

Comment: The states available are based on the **process template** used by the team project. It has nothing to do with the repository.